# Does Kotlin support mutable Strings?

Tags: kotlin

The following code doesn't work in Kotlin:

```
var s: String = "hello"
s[1]='a'
```

Does Kotlin have a mutable string type or do I have to use an `Array<Char>` if I want to be able to edit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

You can use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to manipulate it:

```
val sb = StringBuilder("hello")
sb[1] = 'a'
println(sb.toString())
```

> hallo